# NSNotification in MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller

I'm trying to get just some kind of notification on the buttons pressed in the `MPMoviePlayercontroller`. The problem is that I do not get any kind of notification when the buttons is pressed. I am using `NSNotification` for this. Why am I not getting the notifications?

`ViewDidLoad:`

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(exitedFullScreen)
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification object:nil];
```

and the Method

```
-(void) exitedFullScreen
{
    NSLog(@"TEST");
}
```

code to call the `MPMoviePlayer`:

```
NSString *youTubeVideoHTML = @"<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><style>body{margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;}</style></head> <body> <div id=\"player\"></div> <script> var tag = document.createElement('script'); tag.src = \"http://www.youtube.com/player_api\"; var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag); var player; function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() { player = new YT.Player('player', { width:'%0.0f', height:'%0.0f', videoId:'%@', events: {  } }); } function onPlayerReady(event) { event.target.playVideo(); } </script> </body> </html>";


NSString *embedHtml = [NSString stringWithFormat: youTubeVideoHTML,
                       webView.frame.size.width,
                       webView.frame.size.height,
                       youtubeId[0]];

webView.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction = NO;

[webView loadHTMLString: embedHtml baseURL: [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://youtube.com"]];
```

Comment: How do you create webView is it class property or local variable?

Comment: I used property

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;

Comment: You do not have any MPMoviePlayer and you expect any notifications from MPMoviePlayer

Comment: Well when i click the youtube video in Webview it opens in fullscreen. is that not the MPMoviePlayer?

Comment: There is no such thing as MPMoviePlayer. There is MPMoviePlayerController but there is no MPMoviePlayerController in your code. Your question is misleading.

Comment: sorry i've edited the question. So how can i add the MPMoviePlayerController, so the notification will show.

Comment: You could use MPMoviePlayerController _instead_ of UIWebView. To learn to do that, read the docs, or any tutorial on the subject, or even [my book](http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch28.html#_mpmovieplayercontroller).

Answer (score 1):

Exiting full screen does not change playback state. If you want to know when full screen has been exited, register for `MPMoviePlayerDidExitFullscreenNotification`.

Also, just as a matter of general practice, it is better for your callback method to have a colon (e.g. `exitedFullScreen:`); the parameter is the notification itself:

```
- (void) exitedFullScreen: (NSNotification*) n {
    NSLog(@"%@", @"TEST");
}
```

Comment: i've tested this and i still dont get the test log message ...

Comment: Perhaps something deeper is going on. Are you remembering to retain your MPMoviePlayerController? Show the code by which you create the MPMoviePlayerController, retain it, and put its view into the window.

Comment: Here i the code i use to call the MPMoviePlayer

Answer (score 0):

You should create a `MPMoviePlayerViewController` and initialize with your video url and present it. After you play the video and close it you will get your notification.

Comment: But this means i cant use my loadhtmlstring right? i'm using the API, cause it will play all youtube songs and it will be able to autoplay.

Comment: You will not be able to use loadhtmlstring cuz you don't need it at all. MpMoviePlayerViewcontroller starts automatically when it is presented on the screen. And also there is a property to manage if it starts auto playing.